# is there a replacement for PaaS Service Manager?

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I understand that PSM (this guy here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/java-cloud/pscli/abouit-paas-service-manager-command-line-interface.html) works only with OCP (gen-1 cloud). If this statement is correct, is there a replacement for PSM tht works with OCI (gen-2 cloud)? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PSM CLI to manage PaaS service instances (such as JCS) regardless of whether the instances are deployed on the gen-1 (classic) infrastructure or gen-2 (OCI). The CLI is a wrapper around the PSM REST API, which doesn't touch the underlying infrastructure. I hope this helps.